# How to fix a text file with characters \u2014, \u2017, etc using python?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

A text file has contents like

> "Length: As per client\u2019s need|\u2022 Material: CFC|\u2022"

I'm trying to convert this to characters. How to read, convert this to characters and save it back.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Those `\uXXXX` codes are Python escape literals for unicode characters.  Where did this "text file" come from?  It appears it might have been written by dumping the `repr()`s of some Python `unicode` objects without actually encoding them properly.

Comment: Was this sourced from JSON or from some other source? This matters; different sources encode Unicode codepoints differently. JSON `\uhhhh` codepoints are really UTF-16 values, meaning non-BMP points require **two** escape sequences.

Comment: @AkashTadwai: no, I can't, because there could be other sources of such data that are not JSON, but some other escape sequence system. Sorry, I'm not going to guess, and comments are only here to help improve **this question**, not ask new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, something along the lines of

```
uni_chr_re = re.compile(r'\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})')

lines = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(uni_chr_re.sub(lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1), 16)), line))
```

That's the general approach, but the specifics depend on the details such as where this text came from, as Martijn [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863280/how-to-fix-a-text-file-with-characters-u2014-u2017-etc-using-python#comment80674138_46863280).